# Form recognizer OCR accuracy issue

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, azure-form-recognizer

[Screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkvNH.jpg)I am trying to extract data from Scanned ID cards and having issues with the OCR accuracy. The is some  additional small print behind the names that is getting mixed up with the regular name on ID card. The OCR in form recognizer is not accurate. I tried the computer vision 3.0-preview Read API and that is working correctly. Is there a way to use the new 3.0 computer vision OCR API along with form recognizer 2.0 ? I see some documentation where it mentions using the API for computer vision when using form recognizer in containers? Is it possible for specify the OCR API if we are using the form recognizer API from cloud instead of local containers ?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the image using the FR labeling tool UX at https://fott.azurewebsites.net/ and see whether triggering training from the tool UX helps detect the text better? Form Recognizer's training with labels uses Read 3.0 while the non-label option uses Read 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: The UX at https://fott.azurewebsites.net/ is still not recgnizing the OCR correctly to be able to annotate and train. Added attachment to original question with screenshot